# PeopleEditor control in custom Sharepoint 2010 form not working

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am developing custom form for adding items to a sharepoint 2010 custom list. On my add.aspx site I am using following web controls:

```
<SharePoint:UserField runat="server" ID="Workers" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Workers"/>

<SharePoint:PeopleEditor runat="server" ID="Managers" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Managers"/>
```

as You can see they are connected to specific fields on a list:

```
<Field ID="{1EE0732A-FDD7-4128-A112-BE136DB948D9}" Name="Workers" DisplayName="Workers" Type="UserMulti" Required="TRUE" Mult="TRUE"/>

<Field ID="{1A499D66-B23B-40E4-8306-AF40F9081729}" Name="Managers" DisplayName="Managers" Type="UserMulti" Required="TRUE" Mult="TRUE"/>
```

The problem is that after i fulfill my form and click on save button, new item appear on a list but just with workers field fulfilled. Why it does not work for PeopleEditor control (microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.peopleeditor) ? I realy would like to have this one working as it has Accounts collections which contains all domain\uid of users that where put in this control. How to make it working or how to get from Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor such collection? I need to get those values somehow to perform server side validation on 'save' click event.

BTW. is there somewhere an information which web controls use for each field types?
ie:
**SharePoint:RadioButtonChoiceField - Choice 

SharePoint:TextField - Text 

SharePoint:BooleanField - Boolean**

Comment: have you considered using InfoPath for this form? it will do a lot of this work for you based on the column types.

Comment: unfortunatelly I do not have licence for InfoPath... using trial version is also not possible, thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FormField` it will take the default control template for you, and if you have a custom field it will take the custom control as well.

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="fldTitle" FieldName="Title" ControlMode="New" />
```

Edit: In response to your comments, here is the correct way to parse a user field value:

```
private void ProcessUsers(SPListItem item, string fieldName)
{
  string fieldValue = item[fieldName] as string;
  SPFieldUserValueCollection users = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(item.Web, fieldValue);

  foreach(SPFieldUserValue uv in users)
  {
    SPUser user = uv.User;
    // Process user
  }
```

Comment: and then in code behind on save button click event get the value of fldTitle web control and split it by semicolon to retrieve domain\uid array? That might be a solution. A little nasty but... Maybe someone know how to get domain\uid collection from Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UserField web control in code behind? Or make it working with PeopleEditor as it was asked in problem description?

Comment: No, Just store the value without changing anything.

Comment: But I need to have some specific informations about users that where entered, soo I have to make a split in code behind and get info about each of them.

Comment: you could find how to do it in the answer above.